# Springboot: redirect and reverse-proxy

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, reverse-proxy

I'm having a SpringBoot and SpringMVC **internal** application (internal meaning hidden from the internet by a firewall) and a public authentication (OAuth2) service in the DMZ.

I'm accessing the landing page from the from a client in the internal area.
This page has a login button. When I press it, I'm forwarding the client to the auth server (in the DMZ), that I can access only going through a proxy.

I tried setting the VM env variables:

`-Dhttp.proxyHost=xx -Dhttp.proxyPort=yy -Dhttp.proxySet=true`

and setting them in the `System.properties`

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "http://xx");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "xx");
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");
```

but both with no effect.

I also tried to define a `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` bean :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="requestFactory"
        class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="proxy">
            <bean id="proxy" class="java.net.Proxy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <util:constant static-field="java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP" />
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="java.net.InetSocketAddress">
                        <constructor-arg value="xx" />
                        <constructor-arg value="yy" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

without anymore success.

**Question**

How can I configure Spring to proxify my redirect ?

Thanks!

Comment: Only adding a `requestFactory` won't do much if you don't wire it into an `RestTemplate`. Also why XML if you are using Spring Boot?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to use a RestTemplate. Regarding the XML, I wanted to reuse an XML, without having to create a bean

Answer (score 0):

Got it work as follow (see `restTemplateProxy`)

```
private final String server = "xx";
private final int port = yy;
private final SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpReq = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
private final Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(server, port));
private RestTemplate restTemplateProxy  = null;

{
    clientHttpReq.setProxy(proxy);
    restTemplateProxy = new RestTemplate(clientHttpReq);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "getLightToken", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String getLightToken(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

    /* Header */
    headers.clear();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    /* Body */
    MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();     
    body.add(CLIENT_ID.key, CLIENT_ID.val);
    body.add(CLIENT_SECRET.key, CLIENT_SECRET.val);
    body.add(GRANT_TYPE.key, GRANT_TYPE.val);
    body.add(SCOPE.key, SCOPE.val);

    /* Set the body and header of the request  */
    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    /* Request Authorisation */
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplateProxy.exchange(BASE_URL + TOKEN_URI, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

    return response.getBody();
}
```